# Comparing 2 Arrays & Counting Unique Entries

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm writing an Android application. I have a part where users can add a Location to an array. This location is then used to store history (they clicked button @ time @ location). I need to now count how many times they clicked the button at every location.

Ex:
Arcade: 1
Park: 4
Pool: 0

So far I've been trying to use a HashSet & create a 2d array, but it seems there must be a better way (and I can't get this way to work anyways). Cheers!

Comment: *What* can't you get to work?  Do you have errors?  Stack traces?  What output did you get, what did you expect?  What code did you write for this?

Comment: `Map<Location, Integer>` is the way to go.

Comment: You can have a `counter` attribute in your `Location` class and add it by 1 when the user clicks on it. If you only have the `Location` title atm, you can have a `Map<String, Location>` backed up by a `HashMap` (since you don't need order nor sort of elements) using the `Location` title as key.

Comment: Why is your question title completely different to the question contents?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), or, if you want to use Googles `Guava` libraries, a [`MultiSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) would suit your needs.

From the above link:

> Guava provides a new collection type, Multiset, which supports adding multiples of elements, and counting how many occurrences of each
>   element the multiset contains. Notably, Multiset does not support
>   negative element counts, nor element counts above Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very badly described, especially as the question title does not match the problem description, I think.

If you are using arrays, and you are trying to determine how many entries in one array do not exist in another:

```
List<Integer> aList =  Arrays.asList(a);
List<Integer> bList =  Arrays.asList(b);
int countBefore = aList.size();
aList.retainsAll(bList);
int uniqueCount = countBefore - aList.size();
```

aList will now contain only the elements which are also in bList so comparing the length before and after gives you the number of unique elements in bList.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
private Map<String, HistoryData> historyMap = new HashMap<String, HistoryData>();

private class HistoryData {
    int count;
    List<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
}

private void updateClickCount(String name){
    HistoryData data = getHistoryData(name);
    data.count++;
}
private void addLocatioon(String name, String location){
    HistoryData data = getHistoryData(name);
    data.locations.add(location);
}

private HistoryData getHistoryData(String name){
    HistoryData data = historyMap.get(name);
    if(data == null){
        data = new HistoryData();
        historyMap.put(name, data);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, a lot of times I just need an example to figure it out. It looks like I will likely be able to figure it out thanks to your code. You're awesome!

Comment: Sorry if this is really 'nooby', but what would name refer to? As in the method getHistoryData(String **name**){

Comment: `name` is the name of your component whose record you are trying to keep. e.g. `getHistoryData("Arcade");` `updateClickCount("Park");` etc.